# I'm trying to get 'experiencias` from my data base with relationship one to many, but it returns empty collection, how can I fix it?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm doing a little web application with Laravel and I'm putting information in my data base directly where in my table `Experiencia` I have:

```
id  matricula_id    nombre_Emp  puesto  
1   201618131       1           1
```

this is my `Usuario` model:

```
protected $table = 'usuarios';

protected $fillable = [
 'id',
 'matricula_id',
 'nombres',
 'email',
 'password',
 'facultad',
];

 public function experiencia()
 {
   return $this->hasMany(Experiencia::class,'matricula_id');
 }
```

And my `Experiencia` model:

```
protected $table = 'experiencias';
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'matricula_id',
    'nombre_Emp',
    'puesto',
    'fecha_Ini',
    'fecha_Fin',
];

public function usuario()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(usuarios::class,'matricula_id');
}
```

Both models have fillable `matricula_id`

and my `controller` the function where I want to recover is:

```
public function index($matricula)
{
     $usuario = usuarios::where('matricula_id', $matricula)->with('experiencia')->get();
     dd($usuario->all());
}
```

When I do dd my result is this:

```
array:1 [▼

  0 => usuarios {#282 ▼

    #table: "usuarios"

    #fillable: array:20 [▶]

    #hidden: array:2 [▶]

    #casts: array:1 [▶]

    #connection: "mysql"

    #primaryKey: "id"

    #keyType: "int"

    +incrementing: true

    #with: []

    #withCount: []

    #perPage: 15

    +exists: true

    +wasRecentlyCreated: false

    #attributes: array:24 [▶]

    #original: array:24 [▶]

    #changes: []

    #dates: []

    #dateFormat: null

    #appends: []

    #dispatchesEvents: []

    #observables: []

    #relations: array:1 [▼ 

      "experiencia" => Collection {#279 ▼

        #items: [] <<<<-------- Here is my problem

      }

    ]

    #touches: []

    +timestamps: true

    #visible: []

    #guarded: array:1 [▶]

    #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"

  }

]
```

I expect an array of `experiencia` form my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be calling wrong model actually.

```
public function index($matricula)
{
    $experiencia = Experiencia::with('usuario')->whereHas('usuario', function($usuario) use($matricula) {
        return $usuario->where('matricula_id', $matricula);
    })->get();

    dd($experiencia->all());
}
```

Your model relation also wrong

```
public function usuario()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(usuario::class);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer me, im trying your but I gettin 'Undefined variable: matricula'

Comment: @Jaime I have updated my code. I missed the ```use()``` just now

Comment: My output is '[ ]'

Comment: @Jaime Seems like your relation on Experiencia model is wrong. It should be belongsTo. I updated my answer.

Comment: If i do then my model search 'usuarios.usuario_id', but I dont think is correct cause im searching my foreign key 'usuarios.matricula_id', I update my post with my fillable variables

Comment: It will search for ```id``` instead, not usuario_id. I think your relation is wrong. Foreign key should link to primary key.. But you link foreign with foreign.

Comment: Thanks, I think Im doing my tables wrong and my foreign keys have to link to my primary key, do you know is there a way to link foreign keys to another column in my table? or just to my primary key?

Comment: If you link to other key, it is not a relation anymore. It is just a normal column where you can query the right away without relation. Eg: ```$experiencia = Experiencia::with('usuario')->where('matricula_id', $matricula)->get();``` You can get the list of experiencia right away from a single query.

Comment: Actually before read 'relationship' I commented this in my code Eg: $experiencia = Experiencia::with('usuario')->where('matricula_id', $matricula)->get();, I guess i Found my issue, with my tables and my relations, THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

try this code below;

```
public function show($param = null)
{
    if (!$param) {
        return abort(404, "there is no id present");
    }
    $param = (int) $param;
    $usuario = usuarios::with('experiencia')->where('matricula_id', $param)->first();

     dd($usuario->experiencia);
}
```

for **index** function do not require parameters, and secure your code if parameter has not been sent, dont run the rest of the code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer me, im trying your but I gettin '"Property [experiencia] does not exist on this collection instance."'

Comment: @Jaime could you update your both modal $fillable fields for being more spesific ?